# Scala. How to delete all n'th element from Stream

Tags: scala, stream

Now studying Streams in Scala. Can anybody help me with function that will delete all n'th element from Stream. 
[2,3,99,1,66,3,4];3 must return this: [2,3,1,66,4]

Comment: Note `withFilter` as a lazy filtering, does not create a new collection but forwards filtered values to subsequence map/flatMap/foreach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myStream.zipWithIndex                    //attach index to every element
        .filter(x => (1 + x._2) % n > 0) //adjust index, remove every nth
        .map(_._1)                       //remove index
```

Oops, almost forgot: `filter` and `map` can be combined.

```
myStream.zipWithIndex
        .collect{case (e,x) if (1 + x) % n > 0 => e}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to try doing this without `zipWithIndex` and arrived at:

```
def dropNth[T](s: Stream[T], n: Int): Stream[T] = {
  val (firstn, rest) = s.splitAt(n)
  if (firstn.length < n)
    firstn
  else
    firstn.take(n - 1) #::: dropNth(rest, n)
  }
```

There must be a way to replace the explicit recursion with a fold or scan, but it doesn't seem to be trivial.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not tail-recursive, so for large streams this will cause SOE. (Yes, it is not trivial to do this with `fold`.)

Comment: It's not tail-recursive, but the recursion is lazy, so it won't blow up the stack.  I tested it with an indefinite stream.

Comment: You are right, I stand corrected. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

(In my comment I missed the requirement to omit *all* nth.) Here is a solution with `.zipWithIndex` and `flatMap` based on @jwvh's answer:

```
stream.zipWithIndex.flatMap{ case (v, idx) if (idx + 1) % n > 0 => Stream(v) // keep when not nth
                             case _ => Stream.empty // omit nth
}
```

Here `flatMap` is used like a `filter`. If you need to replace the nth elements with something other than an empty Stream, this might be useful.